# Number items in loop

Tags: python-3.x

Here's the code

```
river_and_countries = { 
    'Nile' : 'egypt',
    'Amazon' : 'Brazil', 
    'yangtze' : 'china', 
    'mississippi' : 'united states of america', 
    'yenisei' : 'russia', 
    'ob' : 'russia', 
    'huang' : 'china', 
} 
num = len(river_and_countries) + 1
n = [value for value in range(1, num)] 

print(f"Following are the longest rivers in the world and their countries (by order):\n")
for x in n:
    for river, country in river_and_countries.items():
        if country == 'united states of america': 
            print(f"{x}. River {river.title()} is in the {country.title()}.") 
        else: 
            print(f"{x}. River {river.title()} in {country.title()}.")
```

I want to print a list of top seven longest rivers and also add a number to them at the front, but for every number it keeps repeating the list.

How can I assign a number to a each river once?

Current output:

```
Following are the longest rivers in the world and their countries (by order):
    1. River Nile in Egypt.
    1. River Amazon in Brazil.
    1. River Yangtze in China.
    1. River Mississippi is in the United States Of America.
    1. River Yenisei in Russia.
    1. River Ob in Russia.
    1. River Huang in China.
    2. River Nile in Egypt.
    2. River Amazon in Brazil.
    2. River Yangtze in China.
    2. River Mississippi is in the United States Of America.
    2. River Yenisei in Russia.
    2. River Ob in Russia.
    2. River Huang in China.
    3. River Nile in Egypt.
    3. River Amazon in Brazil.
    3. River Yangtze in China.
    3. River Mississippi is in the United States Of America.
    3. River Yenisei in Russia.
    3. River Ob in Russia.
    3. River Huang in China.
    4. River Nile in Egypt.
    4. River Amazon in Brazil.
    4. River Yangtze in China.
    4. River Mississippi is in the United States Of America.
    4. River Yenisei in Russia.
    4. River Ob in Russia.
    4. River Huang in China.
    5. River Nile in Egypt.
    5. River Amazon in Brazil.
    5. River Yangtze in China.
    5. River Mississippi is in the United States Of America.
    5. River Yenisei in Russia.
    5. River Ob in Russia.
    5. River Huang in China.
    6. River Nile in Egypt.
    6. River Amazon in Brazil.
    6. River Yangtze in China.
    6. River Mississippi is in the United States Of America.
    6. River Yenisei in Russia.
    6. River Ob in Russia.
    6. River Huang in China.
    7. River Nile in Egypt.
    7. River Amazon in Brazil.
    7. River Yangtze in China.
    7. River Mississippi is in the United States Of America.
    7. River Yenisei in Russia.
    7. River Ob in Russia.
    7. River Huang in China.
    [Finished in 0.2s]
```

Comment: When the system tells you that your question has too much code and not enough text, don't add garbage in the end. Instead read [ask] and follow the advice to better explain the problem. That said, you have two nested loops, and that's why you get the numbers with the duplicate rivers. Remove the outer loop, initialize `n` to 1, and manually increase `n` in the inner loop.

Answer (score 1):

Remove that nested for loop and use the enumerate() function to generate the number:

```
print(f"Following are the longest rivers in the world and their countries (by order):\n")

for i, (river, country) in enumerate(river_and_countries.items(), start=1):
    if country == 'united states of america':
        print(f"{i}. River {river.title()} is in the {country.title()}.")
    else:
        print(f"{i}. River {river.title()} in {country.title()}.")
```

```
Following are the longest rivers in the world and their countries (by order):

1. River Nile in Egypt.
2. River Amazon in Brazil.
3. River Yangtze in China.
4. River Mississippi is in the United States Of America.
5. River Yenisei in Russia.
6. River Ob in Russia.
7. River Huang in China.
```